# Objective C: Switch UITableViewCell when deselecting Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on a prototype (I'm way too green on Objective C) which has a tableview with two different custom prototype cells, each with their own set of components, layout and height. The expected behavior is that when selected, the row expands and shows cell type b, and the previously selected row returns to the former height and cell type.

Ok, so the issue I'm having is that I can't get the previously selected row to change it's cell type, the height is working ok so I end up displaying a shorter version of the expanded cell but not having the components and layout of the desired cell type, and if I scroll through the tableview and return to the location where the previously selected row is it displays the correct cell type, as if it hasn't refreshed the rest of the rows.

Here's my code for tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier;

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    if(indexPath.row == self.selectedIndex){

        CellIdentifier = @"ExpandedCell";
        CollapsedCell *collapsedCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell = collapsedCell;

    }else{

        CellIdentifier = @"LocationCell";
        LocationCell *locationCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        locationCell.transparentBorder.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
        locationCell.transparentBorder.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255 green:255/255 blue:255/255 alpha:0.7].CGColor;
        cell = locationCell;

    }

    BHPlace *currentPlace = self.data[indexPath.row];

    NSString *name = currentPlace.name;

    LocationCell *locationCell = (LocationCell*)cell;
    locationCell.nameLabel.text = name;

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
}
```

and here's the code for my didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.selectedIndex inSection:0] animated:YES];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    self.selectedIndex = (int)indexPath.row;
        NSArray *paths = @[indexPath];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [self goToMarker:self.data[indexPath.row]];
}
```

As usual I'm sure it's a simple issue and there's something I'm not getting right but can't find the right approach,

Thank you all for your time

Comment: add your previously selected row to the `paths` array and reload both cells

Comment: My god, can't believe it was so simple!! If you post this as a separate answer I could mark yours as the accepted answer, thanks a ton btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reload both the previously selected and the newly selected rows -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSMutableArray *paths=[NSMutableArray new];

    if (self.selectedIndexPath != nil) {
        [paths addObject:self.selectedIndexPath];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath animated:YES];
    }

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    [paths addObject:indexPath];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [self goToMarker:self.data[indexPath.row]];
}
```

Note that I changed your `int` property to an `NSIndexPath *` `self.selectedIndexPath`

Comment: Thank you, I too believe it's best to switch the int property to an NSIndexPath, so I'll do just that.